# Where the get messages got ASYNCHRONOUSLY from MQ are kept if the application cannot process it in current moment?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have a conceptual question regarding MQ and Java application.

I have a batch application (java) that will read messages from MQ (set to persist messages) and I have two options, get it sync or assync...

The point is that I'm confused what happens when the async message is sent and the application cannot handle that in that moment. Is the message lost? Kept in any kind of queue (inside the application) or should I handle with exceptions to remake the request when application is available?

MQ > are there resources to process? (no more threads for example) > No > Application > Reject > ?

Was it clear enough?

Comment: Are you inquiring about the IBM MQ product?  If not which specific MQ provider are you asking aout?

Comment: It is IBM MQ v9

Comment: And are you asking specifically about the Asynchronous GET feature?  If so this is only available for non-persistent messages.

Comment: Well at this point I got totally confused...
How async should work? How it is handled if there are no resources to process it?

Comment: I have seen a good write up on it, but if you are using persistent messages, it is not a option.  Basically the queue manager streams a buffer of messages to the client which the client holds in memory, as the client app does gets they come from memory as the memory copy of the messages are consumed the queue manager will send more, if the client crashes the QM does not know if they were processed or not so they are then lost at that point which is the reason it is only supported with non-persistent messages.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the Asynchronous Response feature of MQ and the JMS concept of synchronous and Asynchronous Receive of messages. I imagined the OP was asking about the latter, and you have explained the former.

Comment: @MoragHughson good point Morag, I had not thought they were asking about that concept as they didn't mention JMS or tag the question [jms], but based on the context of a "java batch application" and "get it sync or assync" that may be exactly what they are asking about.

Comment: If you are asking about JMS sync/async concepts this question has some good general explanations of the two "[How to understand the “synchronous” and “asynchronouns” messaging in JMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088873/how-to-understand-the-synchronous-and-asynchronouns-messaging-in-jms)". This article on JavaWorld: "[Transaction and redelivery in JMS](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html)" has a good overview of transacted and non-transacted sessions.

Comment: If you register a JMS async consumer with a Transacted session then you must must call commit to finalize the message being removed from the MQ queue.

Comment: Right, so what I understood from your comments then you need more information about the scenario, so let's clarify this:
1. MQ Queue is configured as SYNC
2. JMS will get it as ASYNC to start several process in batch application
3. The point is, if JMS requests a message, gets the message response but when it get back to the application we have no more resources to process it. Then... what happens?
Does it make sense now? Is this configuration wrong?

Comment: @FelipeC. - Can you add what you mean by "MQ Queue is configured SYNC"? to your question? i.e. show us the queue attributes you are referring to.

Comment: In IBM MQ Explorer, if you click on properties in the queue, you can see an option there called "Response Type" (something like this) that you can set as asyn or sync.
Otherwise in JMS you choose if you will get from queue by sync ir async.
So probably my real doubt, after reading it all is how this relationship behave...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Persistent message is held by MQ on a queue until your getter can get it.

But note this.  If your app is getting Persistent messages, ensure it uses syncpoints (allowing you to commit or rollback).  Then the app can rollback its get if it failed to process the message correctly, and the message will be available on the queue again for the next MQGET.

Comment: this is some great advise, but I don't think it addresses the OP's question which seems to be specifically about Asynchronous GET.  I was asking the OP a few questions to get a better understanding of what he is inquiring about.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will clarify the question, then.  I answered what I thought they asked.

Comment: I added one more comment in my question, please see that

Comment: Are you referring to the "read ahead" optimizations for non-persistent messages?  If so, I invite you to clarify this in your question.  I also refer you to the Knowledge Center page entitled "Improving performance of non-persistent messages".  Be aware that if you use persistent messages inside syncpoints, the read ahead optimizations are not used by MQ.  Messages you get that way will not be held in the client-side buffer.